# Flink's AggregateFunction's getResult() can change Accumulator value?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Can the getResult() function change the value of the accumulator?It still takes effect value when accumulating.
The code is in below:

```
public class WeightedAverage implements AggregateFunction<Datum, AverageAccumulator, Double> {

 public AverageAccumulator createAccumulator() {
     return new AverageAccumulator();
 }

 public AverageAccumulator merge(AverageAccumulator a, AverageAccumulator b) {
     a.count += b.count;
     a.sum += b.sum;
     return a;
 }

 public AverageAccumulator add(Datum value, AverageAccumulator acc) {
     acc.count += value.getWeight();
     acc.sum += value.getValue();
     return acc;
 }
 
 public Double getResult(AverageAccumulator acc) {
     int result = acc.sum / (double) acc.count;
     acc.count = 0; //here
     acc.sum = 0; //here
     return result;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify the accumulator during `getResult`.

Flink will create new accumulators as necessary (e.g., for each new window).